# Random variable sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X$ be random variable representing square of number that fell on die, and $Y$ random >variable which is $-1$ if number on day is less or equal to $4$ and $1$ otherwise.
>   Find distribution of random variable $X+Y$.

My problem is: for example, $P(X+Y=24)=P(X=25$ and $Y=-1)$- is it $0$ since if number $5$ is on die then $Y=1$, or is it $P(X=25)\cdot P(Y=-1)$ where I use fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Are they independent?

Answer (score 2):

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Informally, this is because if we know $X$ then we know something about $Y$, indeed we know everything about $Y$. If you want to do a formal calculation, we have $\Pr(X=25)=1/6$, and $\Pr(Y=-1)=4/6$. Also, $\Pr((X=25)\land (Y=-1))=0$. So $\Pr((X=25)\land (Y=-1))\ne \Pr(X=25)\Pr(Y=-1)$.

But your analysis of why $\Pr(X+Y=24)=0$ is correct.

Note that the value $V$ of the toss the toss is $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, or $6$, each with probability $1/6$. For each of these, compute the value of $X+Y$. We conclude that the random variable $X+Y$ takes on values $0, 3, 8, 15, 26, 37$ each with probability $1/6$.

Comment: But what if variables are given just with distribution,  (X is 1,4,3,16,25,36 each with probability 1/6 and Y is - 1 with probability 2/3 and 1 with probability 1/3) - then we know nothing of dependence or independence?  Can we still assume indenpendance and calculate X+Y